# Tool to track use of "best practices" for each of our apps

Tags: tracking, organization

We have over 100 applications in my company and we are trying to come up with a dashboard to show which applications use continuous integration and unit testing and other best practices.

I was going to put together my own database and a small website to start tracking this but first wanted to ask if there are any products on the market that allow you to track this.

Comment: Don't most continuous integration tools provide a dashboard of all the projects running in them?  Or are you not running all projects on the same CI server?

Comment: yes, but this doesn't help me track or find applications that are NOT using CI, also i can't get metrics like: 56% of our applications are on CI

Comment: If you delegate research, you haven't done it.

Comment: Aiden - i have not idea with that means

Comment: But at least the CI dashboard is something that already exists and you don't have to manually track.  Applications *not* using CI are (total_applications - applications_not_in_CI), and the percentage of applications in CI is (applications_in_CI / total_applications) * 100.  *Nothing* is going to automatically find and track "all applications in your company" - someone's going to have to manually input and update this data somewhere - in a tool / database / wiki / etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I will just throw this :)

We have smth similar on our company, we use inside *wiki* for that, there are list of our software and each responsible developer can comment it, is it using Unit Testing, little documentation attached, maybe an screenshoot, class diagram, a bit of design review. You can customize it as you want. No difference where it will be, on wiki, database, whiteboard, spreadsheet, the most important think is that ppl will have possiblity to edit that, and they will use it.

Comment: i figured db would be better than WIKI because we then can run metrics, like 56% of our applications have unit tests, etc . .

Comment: You can create an custom plugin for wiki, which will update metrics each time you will add smth new, with custom tags and etc. :)

Comment: personally I'd take a db over a wiki too, but to each his own. could probably write this whole app in 15 minutes in django (or any other modern MVC framework) though.

Comment: Looks like a shared spreadsheet would be a good solution for you,it will allow you to do simple calculations easily. You should give Google Docs a try.

Answer (score 1):

Whiteboard.

[image: Whiteboard]
 [$41.29 on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000ONEZXG)

Comment: Or you can make your own: http://lifehacker.com/396995/diy-magnetic-whiteboard-speech-bubble

Comment: global team / applications . . whiteboard not distributed

Comment: A single whiteboard for more than 100 projects doesn't sound like a maintainable solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I really think a custom database with a pretty front-end is your best bet. Hell, a spreadsheet would even do the trick.

Comment: see my above comment to Lukas Šalkauskas

Comment: Spreadsheets can be distributed. I use Google Docs (or Google Apps for your domain) all the time to work on spreadsheets across geographic boundaries.